# `useFindAndModifiaed` is not valid operation while connection to database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently learning backend and also not familiar with it

gritting this error calls 'usefindandmodify' is invalid operation what is this error about???

[image]

it also says
if (VALID_OPTIONS.indexOf(key) === -1) throw new Error(`\`${key}` is an invalid option.`);
^

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import cors from "cors";

const app = express();

app.use(express.json({ limit: "30mb", extender: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extender: true }));
app.use(cors());

const CONNECTION_URL =
"priyanshu74:****@cluster0.2l3k1.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majorityconst PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000"

mongoose
  .connect(CONNECTION_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() =>
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`server running on port: ${PORT}`))
  )
  .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));

mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);
```

Comment: put `"useFindAndModify":false` in connect object option and try again

Comment: no still not working !!! any other solution

Comment: put `mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false);` top of `mongoose.connect`

Comment: no it still says  `useFindAndModify` is an invalid option.......is there any problem in my mondodb server?

Comment: put mongoose.set("useFindAndModify", false); in `then`  of  `mongoose.connect`

Comment: noooo it says .......body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option file:\D:\Programms\MERN\Memories\server\index.js:8:17
Invalid connection string "priyanshu74:priyanshu74@cluster0.2l3k1.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majorityconst PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000"

Comment: is it possible to downgrade mongoose to version 5 ?

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways to soleve this problem
put `useFindAndModify` in `mongoose.connect` option object
and change `extender` to `extended`

```
app.use(express.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
```

or downgrade mongoose to version 5 because `useFindAndModify` has been deprecated
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html#findandmodify

Comment: both of these didnt work.....is there any other option of useFindAndModify ?

Comment: Yess that was solved ...it's inbulit module in express and I was importing it

Comment: problem is solved the error is that when we import files in ES6 we need to to import it with .js extension and i am doing that thing wronf

Answer (score 0):

The `useFindAndModify` option was **deprecated** in version **5.10.0** and was removed in version **6.0.0**.

You can solve this issue by downgrading your mongoose version to **5.10.13**